# How To Order By Id and Parent Id Data

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I have an menu structure in my database with the followin format:

```
Id | Id_Parent | Menu
```

I need to get this data sctructure ordering by `id` and `id_parent` sequential.

How I do this query with linq?

Comment: [`.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)?

Answer (score 6):

```
var orderedData = data.OrderBy(i => i.Id).ThenBy(i => i.Id_Parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

@des answer is correct, but here is same query with query syntax (I find it more readable)

```
var orderedData = from x in data
                  orderby x.Id, x.Id_Parent
                  select x;
```

Comment: Funny, but I never liked the kinder, gentler version.  It's all function calls anyway, so I find the first version easier to understand, at least from an "under the hood" perspective.  Some linq expressions can only be expressed using the dot notation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey maybe it's better for understanding, but I find *Integrated* part of LINQ also very handy (because of it's declarative style)